# Did the Thaicomm-8 SpaceX landed first stage move after landing?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, reuse

The SpaceX Falcon 9 mission that launched the Thaicomm-8 satellite to GTO orbit, landed hard on the OCISLY ASDS barge. One of the legs over extended into the aluminum crush core and did not retract.

Did the stage stay in place while on three legs?

Answer (score 7):

The landing from the video looked pretty X marks the spot on target.

The images on the [SpaceX Flickr feed](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex/26812794034/in/photostream/), it looks like it nailed the X on landing.

[image: Standing Proud on the X]

However, when it came into port it was pretty clear how far it had moved around on the ASDS barge:

[image]

Some of that is the angle of the image, you can see the right most leg is almost on the outer circle, but the leg facing us may have hit the yellow railing or really close to it.  But you can see that the landing in the first photo was well inside the circle.

Looks like three legged, peg-legged first stages have a tendency to wander a bit until they get tied down as in this closeup.

[image: Focus on Engines]

You can see the airplane jackstands they attach to the stage (And these apparently get welded to the deck) and then cables with strain gauges tieing it down even further.

A [picture at Flickr, not allowing downloads](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mseeley1/27145081830/sizes/h/), shows that one of the legs is on top of the barge name writing, showing just how far it really moved.

Some super high res photos of the stage shows some yellow paint on the leg closest to the rail, which is making people think that although it 'walked back' from the edge, it may have actually hit the railing.  See what you think here:

[image: Landing Leg with Yellow paint]

Comment: Me thinks they probably learned some valuable things about transporting the spent boosters this time, and hopefully they will improve in the future!

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto In the other question there is a close up of the wood they shimmed up the stuck leg with. So yep, they are learning all the time, finding edge cases, improving. So much fun to watch.

Comment: The movement of the booster is visible here: https://youtu.be/bvim4rsNHkQ?t=1m20s